# Javascript datestring constructor changes timezone

Tags: javascript

I have a string Date in this format:

> "2012-07-22T08:00:00Z"

But when i try to create a date from that string:

```
new Date("2012-07-22T08:00:00Z");
```

I get:

> Date {Sun Jul 22 2012 01:00:00 GMT-0700}

Looks like it's changing the timezone of the date to local timezone. Because it's reducing the time in 7 hours (**GMT-0700**)

How can i keep the date object with utc and in the right time (**08:00:00**)?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Why do you have a string in the first place? Is it possible to get a timestamp instead?

Comment: the date has UTC functions like `toUTCString()`. Fiddle it using Chrome JS console

Answer (score 3):

It's only showing the date like that because the toString() method of Date returns a date formatted for the current time zone. The internal representation is still time zone neutral. Try `new Date("2012-07-22T08:00:00Z").toUTCString()`.

Javascript Dates have a bunch of methods for getting and setting values either using the current time zone or UTC, so you can use those if you need to calculate or print using UTC.

Answer (score 1):

I looks like UTC and GMT are the same time zone:

http://geography.about.com/od/timeandtimezones/a/gmtutc.htm

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head:

```
function dateToUTC( date ) { 
    return new Date( 
            date.getUTCFullYear(),
            date.getUTCMonth(),
            date.getUTCDate(),
            date.getUTCHours(),
            date.getUTCMinutes(), 
            date.getUTCSeconds()
    ) 
};
```

Seems pretty inefficient though...